# Log Statements work in try block but not it catch block Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have the following code:

```
try {
        Log.debug("TEST 1");
        InputStream input = loadTemplate(template);
        String ofmt = template.getOutputFormat() != null ? template.getOutputFormat().trim().toLowerCase() : "";
        if ("prn".equals(ofmt)) {
            report = createPrinterProcess(template, input);
        } else if (IsImageFormat(ofmt)) {
            report = createImageProcess(ofmt, template, input);
        } else {
            report = createProcess(ofmt, input, new ByteArrayOutputStream());
        }

        return report;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ControllerBase.getRepository().saveError(template, new ServiceError(e));
        Log.warn(String.format("Generate(template, %1$s)", template.getGuid()), e);
        return null;
    }
```

The log statement in the try gets hit and shows up in the log file, but the log statements in the catch block get hit but don't show up in the log file. They are both using the same logger. Any ideas as to what is happening? I just dont understand why logs would work in the try but not the catch. I tried all different levels of logging, all work in the try, none work in the catch.

**EDIT**

My log config, both console and log file are set up the same:
[image]

and this is what saveError looks like, all its doing is saving the error to a .error file, and it is not breaking in the method (i stepped through it):
[image]

Comment: What does `saveError` do? What happens if you put the `Log.warn` *before* that first line? My suspicion is that `saveError` either re-throws the exception in some way or throws an exception of its own.

Comment: Perhaps your `ControllerBase.getRepository().saveError(template, new ServiceError(e));` call is hanging, and so execution does not return to the later lines in the code?

Comment: @JoachimSauer saveError basically saves the exception to a error file.  I tried changing the log to be before that line, still no luck :( whats even weirder is the log statements show up in the console, just not in the log file. All other log statements show up in both!

Comment: @zr0gravity7Iive stepped through the code and it seems that those lines are being executed, nothing unexpected is happening in saveError :(

Comment: It probably has to do with the log level. As your debug log is showing your log level is at least DEBUG, so WARN logs will no be shown. If this is the case, you must set your log level to WARN.

Comment: @whbogado WARN and DEBUG log messages both are picked up by our log, but I went ahead and changed that statement to a Log.debug() statement and it still doesnt show. I also changed the log level to WARN and that didnt change anything. The console and the log file have the same log levels, except those specific logs in the catch show up in the console just not in the file.

Comment: Did you try Log.warn("TEST 2")? Just to rule out any side effect from the other method calls.

Comment: @whbogado Yep, no log statements work in the catch.

Comment: The catch is just a block of code nothing special occurs in there. You say that the logs show up in the console so you have set up the console handler. The only explanation I can think of is that there is something wrong with the saveError logic. It would be useful to see how saveError works.

Comment: @whbogado I added some details that might be helpful

Comment: @whbogado I found this log message in the log: ERROR Unknown object "root" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig is ignored: try nesting it inside one of: ["Appenders", "Loggers", "Properties", "Scripts", "CustomLevels"].